# Is there a way to make a picture box in windows forms c# point towards the co ordinates of my cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a top-down shooter game and I don't know how to make the picture box rotate to a specific point.

```
private void Game_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // this is to handle all the tracking of the mouse
        {
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross; // changes the mouse to a crosshair
            int RotationAngle = 0;

            Point PositionOfMouse = Cursor.Position; // this finds the position of the mouse in the form 
            DisplayForCoOrds.Text = PositionOfMouse.ToString(); // this displays the co ords of the mouse in the form 
            

        }
```

I have found the coordinates of the mouse pointer, but I need to find the angle from which the picture box is to the mouse cursor.

I think I need to do some trigonometry to get this value, but I'm not sure if there is a way in which you can use the RotatateFlip method to rotate to a specific angle.

Comment: [RotatateFlip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rotateflip?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) only allows the [RotateFlipType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rotatefliptype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) as the parameter. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871433/8335151) can help you.

Comment: Why are you using WinForms? use something like [Unity3D](https://unity.com/), it's free and it's c#. WinForms for games is just not the right tool for the job. You get loads of libraries that cover the scenarios you need in games.

Comment: @CobyC I am doing this for my coursework, I would not get as many marks for just using unity and it's pre made libaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `MathF.Atan2(..)` MathF function.

[Wiki on Atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) explains what atan2 is used for.

> The function `atan2 (y,x)` or `arctan2(y,x)` (from "2-argument
> arctangent") is defined as the angle in the Euclidean plane, given in
> radians, between the positive x axis and the ray to the point (x, y) ≠
> (0, 0).

Calculate the [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Euclidean_geometry) in relation to the picture box.
`Vector2 direction = new Vector2(e.X - pictureBox2.Location.X, e.Y - pictureBox2.Location.Y);`

Then calculate the angle using Atan2 and convert the radiant value returned by Atan2 to degrees by multiplying it with the constant 57.2978. See wiki on [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)

then using the code linked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871291/how-do-you-rotate-a-bitmap-an-arbitrary-number-of-degrees/36871433#36871433) to change the bitmap angle.

I used a simple Form with 2 picture boxes on it.

- Assigned picture box 1 a picture as source.
- Leave picture Box 2 blank.
- Implement the code in the `Form1_MouseMove` Event.

***EDIT:***
I changed to code to display a calculated method using the `TranslateTransform(..)` method and another method using the `Matrix.RotateAt(...)` method.

Also implemented the Dispose of the image as suggested by @Jimi

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Image _Image = Image.FromFile(@"S:\Images\next.png");

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        //get the direction of the mouse by looking at the position of the picture box in relation to the mouse pointer
        Vector2 pictureBoxMtxPlane = new Vector2(e.X - pictureBoxMtx.Location.X, e.Y - pictureBoxMtx.Location.Y);
        Vector2 pictureBoxCalcPlane = new Vector2(e.X - pictureBoxCalc.Location.X, e.Y - pictureBoxCalc.Location.Y);

        //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
        //atan2 - calculates the angle between the x axis and the ray line to a point. gt 0
        //57.2978 is a constant used for radians to degrees conversion (One radian is equal 57.295779513 degrees)
        //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian
        float convertToDeg = (180 / MathF.PI);

        float angleMtx = MathF.Atan2(pictureBoxMtxPlane.Y, pictureBoxMtxPlane.X) * convertToDeg;
        float angleCalc = MathF.Atan2(pictureBoxCalcPlane.Y, pictureBoxCalcPlane.X) * convertToDeg;

        //show the angle values on the label controls
        lblMtxDeg.Text = angleMtx.ToString();
        lblCalcDeg.Text = angleCalc.ToString();
        
        //dispose the previously drawn image if there was an image (? - null conditional)
        pictureBoxMtx.Image?.Dispose();
        Bitmap mtxBitmap = new Bitmap(_Image, pictureBoxMtx.Size.Width, pictureBoxMtx.Size.Height);

        pictureBoxCalc.Image?.Dispose();
        Bitmap calcBitmap = new Bitmap(_Image, pictureBoxCalc.Size.Width, pictureBoxCalc.Size.Height);

        //set picture box 2 to the rotated source image.
        pictureBoxMtx.Image = RotateImageMatrix(mtxBitmap, angleMtx);
        pictureBoxCalc.Image = RotateImage(calcBitmap, angleCalc);

    }

    public Bitmap RotateImageMatrix(Bitmap mtxBitmap, float angle)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(mtxBitmap))
        using (var matrix = new Matrix()) {
            //rotate at image mid point
            matrix.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(mtxBitmap.Width / 2, mtxBitmap.Height / 2));
            g.Transform = matrix;
            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
            g.DrawImage(mtxBitmap, new PointF(0, 0));
        }
        return mtxBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap calcBitMap, float angle)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(calcBitMap))
        {
            //move rotation point to center of image
            g.TranslateTransform((float)calcBitMap.Width / 2, (float)calcBitMap.Height / 2);
            //rotate
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            //move image back
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)calcBitMap.Width / 2, -(float)calcBitMap.Height / 2);
            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
            g.DrawImage(calcBitMap, new PointF(0, 0));
        }
        return calcBitMap;
    }

}
```

It looks like this.

[image: Follow Mouse Cursor]

Comment: `57.2978f` is (`180 / Math.PI`, it's usually written like this, it's more clear what kind of conversion is applied). Note that you're leaking a Bitmap on every rotation. You can simply dispose of the previous: `pictureBox2.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox2.Image = RotateImage(b, angle);`. But, you don't really need to create a new Bitmap, you can rotate the World coordinates of the Graphics Context (`Matrix.RotateAt()` is really simple to use) and draw the same Bitmap on a Control's surface, without assigning the Bitmap to a property. It's also quite faster.

Comment: I agree with Jimi, no need to create a new bitmap each time.  Load that bitmap once and store it at form level.  Now handle the PAINT event of the PictureBox and draw that rotated bitmap using the supplied `e.Graphics`.  In the forms mouse move event you'd simply Invalidate() the picturebox causing it to repaint itself.  Do all of the calculations in the Paint() event.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I don't know how MathF works, I thought I would do 'using MathF' but it's a class?

Comment: `MathF` is the *`float`* implementation of the standard `Math` *integer* static class. It contains loads of static methods that is useful in mathematical calculations. You don't have to know how `Math` or `MathF` works. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=netcore-3.1)  explains the methods.  If for some reason you don't want to use the classes built into .Net you will have to calculate *tan* and *Radials / Degrees* to get the same result. You can just do `MathF.TheMethodYouWant(x,y,)` it is static not disposable so you can't use `using(...)` on it.

Comment: In this example you can also use a `Point` or `PointF` like `PointF pictureBoxMtxPlane = new PointF(e.X - pictureBoxMtx.Location.X, e.Y - pictureBoxMtx.Location.Y);` Vectors aren't something that belongs to Unity. It's a scientific / mathematical concept. see [what is a vector](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/what-is-a-vector/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm still not sure what "lblMtxDeg.Text = angleMtx.ToString();" is doing and "using (var matrix = new Matrix())" could you explain or link me to something that would help?

Comment: `lblMtxDeg` is just a label control that I added to the form to show the value of the angle, it is not needed. To understand the `using(...)` statement you can look at [this article explaining IDisposable](https://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/idisposable-and-using-in-c/#:~:text=NET%20way%20to%20signal%20that,and%20SqlCommand%20do%20implement%20IDisposable.). The [Microsoft documentation on Matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) covers what a matrix is. [Matrices in C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyknpOat01w) on YouTube.