# Rotate image from B point to A point

Tags: c#, math, graphics

i have two point, A and B.

i need a formula in **C#** for rotate this picture base two point.

A = * , B = + , . = center of image

```
>image 1
---------------
|  *          |
|      .      |
|          +  |
---------------
>after rotate
---------------
|  *       +  |
|      .      |
|             |
---------------
```

or

```
>image 2
---------------
|          *  |
|      .      |
|  +          |
---------------
>after rotate
---------------
|  +       *  |
|      .      |
|             |
---------------
```

i find a formula for rotate `image 1`, but this formula not working for `image 2`. this formula is:

`float degree = -(float)(Math.Atan2(pointBy - pointAy, pointBx - pointAx) * (180 / Math.PI))`

also i use this function for rotate a bitmap

```
private Bitmap RotateImage( Bitmap bmp, float angle ) {
     Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap( bmp.Width, bmp.Height );
     using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( rotatedImage ) ) {
        g.TranslateTransform( bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2 ); //set the rotation point as the center into the matrix
        g.RotateTransform( angle ); //rotate
        g.TranslateTransform( -bmp.Width / 2, -bmp.Height / 2 ); //restore rotation point into the matrix
        g.DrawImage( bmp, new Point( 0, 0 ) ); //draw the image on the new bitmap
     }

     return rotatedImage;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12025915/5220303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find this formula for image 2

`float degree = -(float)(Math.Atan2(pointAy - pointBy, pointAx - pointBx) * (180 / Math.PI));`