# GDI Resize Image & Guarantee Height

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi+

I'm dynamically creating isometric tiles from standard top-down tiles from another game. The problem, though, is that the the image resize often ends up with some amount of pixels "missing" on either side. I understand they're not really missing and the code is working properly but I don't know enough about GDI to know what settings/tutorials to search for.

I take this: [image] and turn it into this: [image].

It goes from 32x32 to 48x24, which is the correct proportion. However, on the left and bottom, the grass is one pixel short of reaching the edge of the image. I don't want to fix this manually as I'll be doing this for hundreds of tiles so I'd like to find a way to fix this in the code. The issue, in the end, is that the tiles end up with tiny one-pixel gaps between them.

Is there anything I can do with GDI other than just checking each image for the edge colors and adding them manually if they're missing/transparent?

Here's the code I used to do this. The commented out parts are some of the various settings I've been messing with:

```
Bitmap bmp = RotateImage(new Bitmap(fileName), 45);
bmp = ResizeImage(bmp, bmp.Width, bmp.Height / 2);

private static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap rotateMe, float angle)
{
    //First, re-center the image in a larger image that has a margin/frame
    //to compensate for the rotated image's increased size

    var bmp = new Bitmap(rotateMe.Width + (rotateMe.Width / 2), rotateMe.Height + (rotateMe.Height / 2));

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(rotateMe, (rotateMe.Width / 4), (rotateMe.Height / 4), bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

    rotateMe = bmp;

    //Now, actually rotate the image
    Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(rotateMe.Width, rotateMe.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(rotateMe.Width / 2, rotateMe.Height / 2);   //set the rotation point as the center into the matrix
        g.RotateTransform(angle);                                        //rotate
        g.TranslateTransform(-rotateMe.Width / 2, -rotateMe.Height / 2); //restore rotation point into the matrix
        g.DrawImage(rotateMe, new Point(0, 0));                          //draw the image on the new bitmap
    }

    return rotatedImage;
}
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        //graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        //graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        //graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider calculating the Width and Height of your rotated object.

For example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var width = (int) numericUpDown2.Value;
        var height = (int) numericUpDown3.Value;
        var angle = (float) numericUpDown1.Value;
        var size = new Size(width, height);
        var result = RotatedSettings(angle, size);
        textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} x {1}", result.Width, result.Height);
    }

    private static Size RotatedSettings(float angle, Size size)
    {
        // setup corner values in array
        var corners = new[]
        { new PointF(0, 0),
          new PointF(size.Width, 0),
          new PointF(0, size.Height),
          new PointF(size.Width, size.Height)};

        // rotate corners
        var xc = corners.Select(p => Rotate(p, (float)angle).X);
        var yc = corners.Select(p => Rotate(p, (float)angle).Y);

        // find the new sizes by subtracting highest from lowest result.
        var widths = xc as IList<float> ?? xc.ToList();
        var newWidth = (int)Math.Abs(widths.Max() - widths.Min());
        var heights = yc as IList<float> ?? yc.ToList();
        var newHeight = (int)Math.Abs(heights.Max() - heights.Min());

        // as we rotate the mid point we need to middle midpoint section and add the outcome to size.
        var midX = ((size.Width / 2) - ((double)newWidth / 2));
        var midY = ((size.Height / 2) - ((double)newHeight / 2));

        return new Size(newWidth + (int)midX, newHeight + (int)midY);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates a point around the origin (0,0)
    /// </summary>
    private static PointF Rotate(PointF p, float angle)
    {
        // convert from angle to radians
        var theta = Math.PI * angle / 180;
        return new PointF(
            (float)(Math.Cos(theta) * (p.X) - Math.Sin(theta) * (p.Y)),
            (float)(Math.Sin(theta) * (p.X) + Math.Cos(theta) * (p.Y)));
    }
```

Comment: This returns a size that doesn't match the isometric proportion. An isometric image based on a perfect square should have a width 50% larger and a height 25% shorter. It's essentially rotating an image 45 degrees on the z-axis (spinning right/left) and then rotating -45 degrees along the x-axis (tilting the top of the image back). Your method returns 39x39. My normal rotation actually works fine. I know that the image should be 48x24, and it is, it's just a matter of the "tilting back" part, which I do by shrinking the height 50%. I'm not sure if I'm missing something else from your solution.

Comment: You are right. I gave a solution to get the bounds on a 2D rotation. I did not read the question right. perhaps this thread will help you a little further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp

Comment: a 3D library example using Quaternion mathematics on 3D rotating in GDI. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36868/Quaternion-Mathematics-and-D-Library-with-C-and-G for an 3D library example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll spend some time going through these and update if I get a solution.