# After Encode to base64 image rotated by 90 degres

Tags: c#, windows, image, windows-phone-8.1, base64

in my app I'm uploading images to server. I encode image from my WP 8.1 and send it to server. Sending and receiving work well but I have problem with image. I don't know why but whem I uploaded the image photographed on portrait after decoding is this image rotated by 90 degrees. Landscapes images are good, but portrait are rotated. Here is my encode and decode code

Encode:

```
 private async Task<string> StorageFileToBase64(StorageFile file)
        {
            string Base64String = "";

            if (file != null)
            {
                IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[fileStream.Size];
                reader.ReadBytes(byteArray);
                Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
            }

            return Base64String;
        }
```

Decode image on server

```
public void ShowImg(string b64)
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
                // Convert byte[] to Image
                var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);


                f.pictureBox1.Image = image;

            }
```

Comment: `Landscapes images are good, but portrait are rotated.` If you are not doing anything special for it, then why do you think your code is the problem. Maybe it is how the server handles your image....

Comment: You can rotate when decode image ? [How do I rotate a picture in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160437/4869467)

Comment: Yeah, but i don"t know if uploaded image is in landscape or portrait format

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am seeing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string startExpression = "data:image/png;base64,";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   ms.Flush();       
   System.Drawing.Image imageIn = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName);  
   ms.Position = 0;                              
   imageIn.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
   imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   var bytes= ms.ToArray();
   string fileBase = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); 
   var base64= startExpression + fileBase;
   imageIn.Dispose();
   ms.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.