# Rotating an image and the container control in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, image, rotation

I am looking for a .NET Winform component with the functionality similar to picture box in MS Power Point that you can easily insert an image from a file and using mouse you can easily rotate or resize the image and the container control.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I need is a ready to use control (ie. a thrid party component) that I can move, resize, rotate it at run time in winform .NET. My ideal control is something similar to MS PowerPoint picture control.

Comment: Then see the codeproject link. You can roll your own as well by forming a usercontrol. I will be glad to see one if you could post somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times. See [How do I rotate a picture in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp) or [Rotate image math (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472428/rotate-image-math-c)
 or [on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations). You should basically use a [PictureBox](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx&ei=-YKNUPHeCojNrQfcloCQBw&usg=AFQjCNFX4i2m6hV3rt2h4DYvy1cpSfj7tQ&sig2=0DTMW6G-K6Fifmr049hoEw) as the container control as control is meant for these kind of operations.

Comment: I already used picturebox in my application for different purpose. What I need is a ready to use control (ie. a thrid party component) that I can move, resize, rotate it at run time in my .NET winform porject. My ideal control is something similar to MS PowerPoint picture control

Comment: @Siamak I doubt if they exist. Please see to third party user controls on telerik or devexpress, but I suspect they come at a heavy price..

Comment: Thanks nawfal for your prompt response.I already checked their site and did not find what I need. What I need seems to be something that many people already needed but unexpectedly I did not find any ready to use winform control even non-free one.