# Rotate PictureBox change size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a picture box, size 710x238 that I'm using to display an image that is much larger. When I load the image, It loads the image without distorting it. It works great. But when I rotate the image and try to display that in the PictureBox, the image size change to a square...

How do I rotate the PictureBox along with the image so that the rotated image is not distorted?

Here is my code

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; //property for load without distorting
```

and the code for rotate (this code rotate the Image...I wanna rotate the pictureBox)

```
Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
float angle = 90;
var newBitmap = new Bitmap(oldBitmap.Width, oldBitmap.Height);

var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
graphics.TranslateTransform((float)oldBitmap.Width / 2, (float)oldBitmap.Height / 2);
graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)oldBitmap.Width / 2, -(float)oldBitmap.Height / 2);
graphics.DrawImage(oldBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
pictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
```

How can I rotate the PictureBox? I wanna rotate the PictureBox along with the Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I finally understand what you need. Keep the SizeMode as Zoom and try this:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; // or PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

...

int height = pictureBox1.Height;
int width = pictureBox1.Width;
pictureBox1.Width = height;
pictureBox1.Height= width;
pictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
```

Comment: but the PictureBox will distort the image...or no?

Comment: It will clip the image to the boundaries of the PictureBox, but not "distort" it (stretch/scale it)

Comment: but I need that the image appears full in pictureBox, the  PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom works, but when rotate it resize the image wrong

Comment: Ah, you want to rotate the PictureBox to fit the image. See my edit.

Comment: but I dont need that the pictureBox have the same size from image..The image is bigger than the picBox..I use sizeModo.Zoom for stretch the image ...but when I rotate the image...I need the same size before rotate but rotated....

Comment: Zoom will stretch the image to fit the picture box, so of course it will distort the image when it rotates. After your image is rotated, it no longer has the same aspect ratio, relative to the PictureBox, that it had before rotating.

Comment: Can you size your PictureBox as 710x710 and use PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal?

Comment: How can I rotate the PictureBox...The code from my question rotate the Bitmap

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26161/discussion-between-illdev-and-kohanz)

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode =PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

if you want to rotate `PictureBox` you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472428/rotate-image-math-c)